# How to display json file without calling it directly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I've been poking around a great website - http://beta.rallyinteractive.com/ trying to learn something new. Website uses a lot of Ajax in it, and also some interesting javascript - without any additional libraries.

In this single javascript file a found a reference to ajax json get request. You can even easily access the the json file on this url http://beta.rallyinteractive.com/surrounding/studio/ , however I do not understand, why is this data being shown, without the "proper" path to the file.

And by proper I meant "somedomain.com/surrounding/studio/**data.json**"

Any ideas?

Comment: It is the proper path to the file thanks to how the server is set up.

Comment: URLs do not need to correspond to files.

Comment: The same way you go to Google.com/ and a page shows, even though the correct path is Google.com/index.html (example)

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way they have their site hosting setup on the server and/or within the web application. If you request to the "/surrounding/studio/" folder then it returns the JSON response.